# Question about recurrence relation problem.

Tags: recurrence-relations, solution-verification

[image]

solve the following recurrence relation, subject to given initial conditions.

$a_{n+1} = 6a_n -9,$

$a_0 = 0,$

$a_1 = 3.$

Here is what I have done.

$a_{n+1} - 6a_n +9 = 0$

$a_n = r^n$

$r^{n+1} - 6r^n + 9 = 0$

$r + 6 = 0$

$r = -6$

$a_n$ = $X(-6)^n$

$a_1 = 3 = X(-6)^1$

$X = -1/2$

Therefore

$a_n = -1/2(-6)^n$

Am I on the right track or are there any mistakes I made somewhere?

***Edited:*** added the capture of the problem

Comment: Have you checked to see whether your answer satisfies the recurrence relation? (It doesn't).

Comment: I added a capture of the problem too see if I entered something wrong but it seems I have entered everything correct.

would it be a mistakes from my lecturer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
a_{n+1}&=6a_n-9\\
a_{n+1}-\frac95&=6a_n-\frac{54}5\\
&=6\left(a_n-\frac95\right)\\
u_{n+1}&=6u_n\\
u_n&=6u_{n-1}=6^2u_{n-2}=\cdots=6^{n-1}u_1\\
&=6^{n-1}\left(a_1-\frac95\right)\\
&=6^{n-1}\left(3-\frac95\right)\\
a_n-\frac95&=\frac65(6^{n-1})\\
&=\frac{6^n}5\\
a_n&=\frac15\left(9+6^n\right)\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$

*Check:*
$$\begin{align}
6a_n-9&=\frac65(9+6^n)-9\\
&=\frac95+6(6^n)\\
&=\frac15(9+6^{n+1})\\
&=a_{n+1}
\end{align} $$

*Hence formula is correct.*

Answer (score 0):

This recurrence relation is nonhomogeneous, and cannot be solved directly using the characteristic polynomial (terms in the characteristic polynomial correspond to coefficients of $a_i$). Instead, try the following:
\begin{align*}
   a_{n+1} &= 6a_n-9 \\
   a_{n+2} &= 6a_{n+1}-9.
\end{align*}
Subtract the first equation from the second; this should give a second-order linear recurrence, which you *can* solve using the method above.